# How to sort elements inside the arraylist in java?

Tags: java, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an arraylist of objects java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145523/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-of-objects-java)

I have an arraylist that contains very large details i want to sort the data alphabetically but there is no method in arraylist class for sort. Please Help?

Comment: Huh didn't realize google was broken today..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no sort method in arraylist But there is a sort method in Collections as ArrayList comes under the collections tree structure you can use the sort of method in collections.Here is the code `Collections.sort(arrayList);`

Comment: Don't do that, you can see @A.R.S. already answered that.

Comment: Duplicates are bad. Accepted duplicates are worse. By the way not every collection is sortable.

Comment: I am not an java specialist all I wanted is to sort alone and not to get things complicated that is why i accepted this answer.But Your answer should elaborate well to other users who know java well.As I am new i choosed simple is best.Northing more in accepting your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)), which is able to sort any `List`.

I'm assuming that you're talking about a list of strings, in which case you can simply call `Collections.sort` on your list to sort it alphabetically.

If you're referring to a list of instances of a class you created with an internal string field then you have two options:

- Have the class implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, then call `Collections.sort` on the list with no arguments other than the list itself.
- Write a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that works with your class, and pass an instance of it to the `sort` method as a second argument along with your list.

If alphabetical ordering is the 'natural' way in which instances of your class should be ordered, you should probably implement `Comparable`. If not, you should probably write a `Comparator`.

Comment: And write your own Comparator

Comment: @duffymo I was assuming it was a list of strings, but if not yes.

Comment: "array of objects" - no explicit mention of String.

Comment: @duffymo Alright, I updated my answer anyway, thanks for the notice.